# How to play mpg/3gp 5 sec video at start of application?

Tags: android, video, 3gp, mpeg

I am developing an application in which i want to play a short 5 seconds video at the startup. which is the best format 3gp, mpg or something else? i have generated a title activity. I wanted to play the video before title. Help please!!! Below is the code of my title activity.

```
public class Title extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.title);
        setTitle("M.I.S.T");
        this.setTitleColor(Color.BLUE); 
        View title = getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        View titleBar = (View) title.getParent();
        titleBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent open= new Intent("com.congestion6.asad.MENU");
                    startActivity(open);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: use video view to play video.....And on video end call intent of new activity.

Comment: Thanks for your response!. Do i need to make any changes in my layout as well? and also tell me can i play mpg video?

Comment: as per my knowledge i think not possible. use other formats.

Answer (score 0):

**mpeg** can be compressing the video over a range of different formats/algorithms/codecs and some are supported some are not. 3gp is just one and it is supported (although a very poor format).

Try encoding a video yourself that you'll see all different options. Usually **mp4** on **H264** works flawlessly on mobiles.